# Populate input fields on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following `HTML` form:

```
<form action="http://.../index.php/timer/start_timer" class="start_timer" id="start_timer" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="shift_id" value="290">
    <input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="latitude">
    <input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="longitude">
    <input type="submit" value="Start">
    </form>
```

On the `submit` button press I would like to set the values for `latitude` and `longitude` fields and the proceed with the action to my controller.

Here is the `JavaScript` function for getting `lat` and `long`.

```
function startStopTimerSubmit(){

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundLocation, noLocation);

}

function foundLocation(position){

    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById('latitude').value = lat;
    document.getElementById('longitude').value = long;

}

function noLocation()
{
    alert('Could not find your location. Please, try again.');
}
```

What would be the most reasonalbe way to fill the values (`js` and `jQuery` are OK) and then proceed with the logic?

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: defining function in another function is bad practice.

Comment: Correct and thanks. This has been updated. However, the proper way of solving this is still in question.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar — No, it isn't. It's a core feature of JS used for scoping.

Comment: @Quentin: hi, before edit you are saying?wouldn' that redifine function everytime when first method is invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a nice way to do this.

Since `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, the only way to do it would be to:

1. Prevent the default submit behaviour
2. Trigger the async function
3. Populate the fields in the callback
4. Trigger the form submission with JavaScript

It would be easier to simply try to populate the fields when the page loaded so that by the time the form was filled in, the data would be there.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the field has been populated before continuing with a nested function. This would like something kind of like...

```js
function submit() {
  var latField = $('.lat-field');
  
  getLatLng(function(lat, lng) {
      latField.val(lat);
      latField.hasValue = true;
      submit(); //call submit again now value has been populated
  });
  
  //dont proceed if value has not been set
  if( !latField.hasValue ) return;
  
  //Your standard functionality here
}
```